# build dynamic mysql query with multiple where condition

Tags: php, mysql

i have below query and it work fine.
but if the `$where` were  array it will be fail,what's the solution?

```
 public function update($tbl_name, $data = NULL, $where = NULL)
{

    if ($data) {

        $data_key = array_keys($data);
        $where_key = array_keys($where);

        $query = "UPDATE " . $data['db_table'] . " SET ";
        foreach ($data_key as $key) {
            $query .= "`" . $key . "` = '" . $data[$key] . "' ";
        }
        //todo fix that for multi where
        $query.=" WHERE `".$where."`=".$where[''];
        return $this->query($query);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to determine if the where variable is an array or not if it is you'll have to iterate through it and write out the where clause as a string to a new variable then print that in the SQL query statement.

Comment: You'll need a `WHERE IN ( array elements )` for filtering on multiple values. If the array elements are text, then you'll need to surround them in quotation marks. Regardless of the element type, you'll need a comma separator between values.

Comment: thanks,I update code.can anyone give me the correct code.

Comment: `$where` is an array of what thing? values? conditions? a pair of field-value? other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that this is a rather dangerous thing that you are doing? Chances of your database getting nuked by someone entering something unexpected is way too high. As for the where clause, you can get help from [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

```
if(is_array($criteria)) {
    $query.=" WHERE `".$where." IN (" . join(",", $criteria) . ")";
}
else {
    $query.=" WHERE `".$where." = '{$criteria}'";
}
```

The other issue here is that never ending string concatenation of this nature leads to very hard to trace bugs.